# ACF: Update a sub field inside a group field nested inside another group field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a frontend form for creating a **CPT** that takes in various details supposed to update the ACF fields associated with that **CPT**. On form submission, the **CPT** gets created and the simple ACF *text, number* etc fields get saved as well. But I am unable to update the `sub_fields` nested deep inside a  `group` field. This is the structure of my main **ACF Field group**:

```
'Working hours' (field_61f453c010074 - Type: Group)

   a. 'Monday' Group Field (field_61f4570e89281 - Type: Group)
       * 'Am' Sub Field #1 (field_61f4573589282- Type: Number)
       * 'Pm' Sub Field #2 (field_61f4574589283- Type: Number)

   b. 'Tuesday' Group Field (field_61f7a30ffbcf0- Type: Group)
       * 'Am' Sub Field #1 (field_61f7a30ffbcf1- Type: Number)
       * 'Pm' Sub Field #2 (field_61f7a30ffbcf2- Type: Number)
```

and it goes on like that till Sunday. I have tried various approaches but to no avail. And there are no errors generated in the process.

My code demo for updating the '**Am**' field of **Monday**:

```
if( have_rows('field_61f453c010074') ): while ( have_rows('field_61f453c010074') ) : the_row(); 

    if( have_rows('field_61f4570e89281') ): while ( have_rows('field_61f4570e89281') ) : the_row();       

        update_sub_field('field_61f4573589282', $_POST['am']);

    endwhile; endif;

endwhile; endif;
```

I also tried this:

```
$value = array(
    array(
        "field_61f4570e89281"   => array(                
            "field_61f4573589282"   => $_POST['am'],
            "field_61f4574589283"   => $_POST['pm']
        )

);
update_field( 'field_61f453c010074', $value, $post_id  );
```

Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7mZP.png)

```
$value = array(
    // nested array for every row of repeater
    array(
      // field key => value pairs for each sub field
      'field_62e5ba3233ceb' => 'block title', // title field
      'field_62e6bd4119dc1' => array(
        // nested repeater
        // field key => value pairs for each sub field
        array(
          'field_62e6bd5e19dc3' => 'link title',
          'field_62e6bd6419dc4' => 'link url',
          'field_62e6bd6a19dc5' => 'link fa icon',
        ),
        array(
          'field_62e6bd5e19dc3' => 'link title',
          'field_62e6bd6419dc4' => 'link url',
          'field_62e6bd6a19dc5' => 'link fa icon',
        ),
      ),
      'field_62e6c641a4fb4' => array(
        // nested repeater
        // field key => value pairs for each sub field
        'field_62e6c64ba4fb5' => 'link title',
      ),
      // next row in nested repeater
    ),
    // next row in repeater
  );

  update_field($repeater, $value, $post_id);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).